# Can an element have infinitely many factors while each of its chain of factors eventually stabilize?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is it possible to find an integral domain $R$, and $a\in R^*\backslash U(R)$, such that $a$ has infinitely many not equivalent factors, whereas each chain of factors of $a$, $a_0=a>a_1>a_2>\cdots$ will eventually stabilize, i.e., $\exists n,~ a_{n}\sim a_{n+1}\sim a_{n+2}\sim\cdots$? Here $x>y\iff y\mid x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.